# How do I compare two directories while ignoring certain directory names?

Tags: linux

I want to iteratively compare two directories, A and B, under Linux using:

```
diff -r ./A ./B
```

but I want to ignore some subdirectory names, e.g. a subdirectory called "svn".

How do I do it under Linux?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write:

```
diff -r --exclude=svn ./A ./B
```